# Only show in stock products OpenERP

Tags: openerp-7

When I open the location structure of the warehouse and check the current inventory of a particular location, it shows me all products (even when stock is 0). 
Is there a way to hide the products that are not in stock in that particular location (or remove them from being able to show in that location)?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this functionality, you have to customize addons side code of stock and product,

You have to implement funt_search method in qty_available function of product,  to search product based on codition.

And in the wizard you have to pass domain, of qty_avalable > 0 at wizard,.

For refrence you can see in openerp latest trunk stock module code.

Hope this help